# Lotus Note integration

Tags: email, integration, calendar

Anyone has experience with bidirectional email and calendar integration with Lotus Notes (salesforce to note, server-to-client) or even with Lotus Domino (salesforce to domino, server-to-server)? I've seen there are some *connector* on the internet but I'm quite new both to salesforce (and to *connector* concept) and to IBM lotus software.

I'm looking for something that can be used also with mobile applications (iOS and Android mainly), and integrated with IBM Traveller and iNotes.

Maybe some clarification?

Answer (score 0):

LinkPoint use to be one of the best Notes connectors around - worth having a look at this one

Comment: Yes thanks but it seems to be only desktop windows, see my edits.